# Upload image in Document object in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I need help in following code. I need to put my images in document object of Salesforce. Currently I am putting in notes and attachment which is fine, with this I need to put in Document object.

I need to do this because image not displaying in Word file but they displayed in PDF.

```html
@RestResource(urlMapping='/SyncAttachments/*')
global with sharing class AssessmentApp_SyncAttachmentsWebService {

global class Image {
   public String primaryKey;
   public String base64;
   public String parentId;
}

@HttpPost   
    global static Map<String, String> syncAttachments(Image image) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.Info, 'image ' + image);
        List<Attachment> attachments = [SELECT Id, Name, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id =:image.primaryKey];
        System.Debug('attachments ' + attachments);
                    //check if attachment is already present. If not, create a new one.
                    Attachment myAttachment;
                    if (attachments.size() == 0) {
                        //Check the parentId of the attachment. Check if parentId belongs to notes
                        myAttachment = new Attachment();
                        myAttachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(image.base64);
                        myAttachment.ContentType = 'image/jpg';
                        
                        myAttachment.Name = image.parentId;
                        
                        myAttachment.ParentId = image.parentId;
                        insert myAttachment;
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        myAttachment = attachments[0];
                    }

                
        Map<String, String> responseMap = new Map<String, String>();
        responseMap.put('Success', '1');
        responseMap.put('Message', 'Sync Attachment ' + myAttachment.Name + ' Successfully');
        return responseMap;
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept the `@RestResource` `urlMapping` parameter the same, with the wildcard, so the URI would stay the same. The method name also stayed the same. It would be ideal if you updated both of these, as well as your calls upstream, to say "Document" instead of "Attachment."

There is no field `ParentId` on `Document` like on `Attachment`, so parenting logic was not included. You also need to assign each `Document` into a `Folder`, you can change `FolderId` to assign them correctly. This will throw an exception if there aren't any `Folders` in your org.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/SyncAttachments/*')
global with sharing class AssessmentApp_SyncAttachmentsWebService {

    global class Image {
       public String primaryKey;
       public String base64;
       public String parentId;
    }

    @HttpPost   
    global static Map<String, String> syncAttachments(Image image) {
        List<Document> documents = [SELECT Id, Name, Body FROM Document WHERE Id =:image.primaryKey];
        Folder dummyFolder = [SELECT Id FROM Folder LIMIT 1];
        Document myDocument;
        if (documents.size() == 0) {
            myDocument = new Document();
            myDocument.FolderId = dummyFolder.id;
            myDocument.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(image.base64);
            myDocument.ContentType = 'image/jpg';
            myDocument.Name = image.parentId;
            insert myDocument;
        }
        else {
            myDocument = documents[0];
        }       
        Map<String, String> responseMap = new Map<String, String>();
        responseMap.put('Success', '1');
        responseMap.put('Message', 'Sync Document ' + myDocument.Name + ' Successfully');
        return responseMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Brain - A lot of thanks for immediate response .... I will check with stuff and will let you know about it....I will take help if some need required from you

Comment: is possible to tell u that, I would like to display images from  attachment & notes objects in word file. Above solution is great but we are not able to service where past employe has written and I am new to salesforce.